# Consume a paginated Iterable[T] as if it was a continuous Iterable[T]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm using a service that returns me paginated resources. It exposes one single call, which is defined by the following interface:

```
trait Service {
    getPage(pageSize: Int, pageCursor: String): AsyncPage[Resource]
}
```

The `getPage` function returns an `AsyncPage[T]` object, which is implemented like this:

```
/**
 * A page of contents that are retrieved asynchronously from their origin
 *
 * @param content The resource object
 * @param nextPageCursor The token representing the next page, or empty if no more pages to consume
 * @tparam T The type of resource withing the page
 */
case class AsyncPage[T](
  val content: Future[Iterable[T]],
  val nextPageCursor : Future[String]
) { }
```

The contents of the page are retrieved asynchronously from whichever storage system the service uses.

Because of the needs of my application, I don't really care about pages. I'd like to code something that allows me to consume the resources of the service as if it was a single `Iterable[T]`.

However, I want to maintain the lazyness of the service. I don't want to request more pages than necessary. That means that I don't want to request the next page until I haven't consumed all the elements of the previous one.

Whenever I have consumed the whole `Iterable[T]` of one page, I want the code to request the following page using the `getPage(...)` function, and providing the `pageCursor` parameter from the last page `nextPageCursor`.

Can you guide me on how to achieve that?

Comment: Should the `Iterable[T]` block on these `Future`s then? Otherwise I think the best you can do is an `Iterable[Future[Iterable[T]]`.

Comment: My application is based on the Akka actor-model framework, which discourages blocking the actor thread and tells you to work purely asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't mind blocking, you can do something like this:

```
 class FutureIter[+P](fu: => Future[Iterator[P]]) extends AbstractIterator[P] {
   lazy val iter = Await.result(fu)
   def hasNext = iter.hasNext
   def next = iter.next 
 }

  def fold[T](fs: Stream[Future[Iterator[T]]]): Iterator[T]= fs match {
    case hd #:: tail => new FutureIter(hd) ++ fold(tail)
    case _ => Iterator.empty
  }

  val pages = Stream
    .iterate(getPage(size, "")) { getPage(size, _.nextPageCursor) }
    .map(_.contents.map(_.iterator))

  val result: Iterator[T] = fold(pages)
```

This will block before the first page, and at the end of each subsequent page to load the next batch. I don't think there is a way to do this without blocking, because you can't tell where the page ends until the future is satisfied.

Also, note that the iterator this code produces is infinite, because you didn't mention any criteria when to stop looking for more pages. You can tuck some `.takeWhile` call onto the `pages` to correct that.

You may also want to replace `Stream` with `Iterator` so that pages you are done with get discarded immediately, rather than getting cached. I just used `Stream` because that makes `fold` a little bit nicer (you can't match on iterators, would have to use and ugly `if(it.hasNext) ...` instead).

BTW, `fold` looks like it is recursive, but it actually is *not*: `++` is lazy, so the `fold(tail)` piece will not be executed until you have iterated all the way through the left-hand-side - well after the outer `fold` is off the stack.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't tried your solution yet, will do tomorrow. However, I've been doing some research and found this [link](http://koff.io/posts/pagination-and-streams/) where the author presents three implementations to turn the paging source into an asynchronous stream. I can see the recursive version relying on locking, too. I'm not sure about the other solutions. As I posted in another comment, the application I'm working on uses the Akka actor-model, which discourages locking the main thread (possibly executing the asynchronous tasks in a different ExecutionContext)

Comment: You should definitely NOT lock the main thread. Off-loading the whole thing onto a background thread is the usual way: `val result: Future[Iterator[T]] = Future(fold(pages))`

Comment: The code in the link you reference doesn't exactly do what you were asking - it shows different ways to traverse paginated results (there are plenty), not "flatten" them into an iterator of values (which is one of many ways to traverse them).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned akka, you could create a `Source[T]` which can sort of be though of as an async `Iterable[T]`:

```
Source.unfoldAsync[String, T](startPageCursor) { cursor =>
  val page = getPage(pageSize, cursor)
  for {
    nextCursor <- page.nextPageCursor
    it <- page.content
  } yield Some((nextCursor, it))
}.mapConcat(identity)
```

This is much cleaner and completely non-blocking. But it is up to your use case if this is suitable.